# How can I get public IP address in python programetically. I don't want to hit any 3rd party service url to get the IP

Tags: python, ip, fastapi, public

I want the public IP address for specific IP allowed for my project preference .
But I don't want to use any 3rd party service url to get the

IP

. I am using python and fastapi

I can't find anything without 3rd party or paid services

Comment: "for specific IP" It sounds like you already know the IP address.  So I don't even understand what you are asking for...

Comment: Actually I  have a need my application where i will give access from specified ip to access the routes . So for that I need to get the user public network ipv4 ip which I will use in middleware to do that.

But I don't want to use any 3rd party websites which returns my public IP

: I am using FASTAPI

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get your routers public (external) IP address then this code should work:

```
import requests

try:
    public_ip = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org').text
    print(f"Public IP Address: {public_ip}")
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error retrieving public IP address: {e}")
```

Comment: ipify is an external website and I have to depend on that. and also it has rate limit of 1000 hits/month for free account. also I don't want to use any  3rd party website to grab that